# In what context can I see effect of sudo's "--preserve-groups" option?

Tags: sudo, group

Given the following users:

```
$ whoami
admin
$ groups
staff everyone admin groupA
```

and

```
$ whoami
user
$ groups
staff everyone groupB
```

I'm trying to understand what exactly the `--preserve-groups` option affects.

```
$ whoami
admin

$ sudo --preserve-groups -u user groups
staff everyone groupB

$ sudo --preserve-groups -u user -s groups
staff everyone groupB

$ sudo --preserve-groups -u user -i groups
staff everyone groupB
```

The way I read the option's documentation I expect the list of groups, as seen by the executed command, to be taken from the invoking user and not from the target user. But it appears to be not the case.

Comment: That’s what I referred as option’s documentation in my question.

Comment: I think that `admin` the group in this case is the primary group of the `admin` the user, and note that the manpage says "The real and effective group-IDs, however, are still set to match the target user", so you can't inherit the primary group. Maybe try `sg everyone` or `sg staff` before using `sudo`

Comment: In reality there are other groups that are unique to admin and user respectively. The result is the same: group-vector of admin is not preserved as seen by the groups command. I suspect that it is preserved somewhere else, I just cannot come up with and example that’d demonstrate it.

Comment: Huh, weird, then. It works fine enough for me on macOS 12.3.1 (1.9.5p2) and Arch Linux (sudo 1.9.10) (e.g., by comparing the output of `sudo -u daemon groups` with `sudo -u daemon --preserve-groups groups` - on both I could see my groups in the output of the latter command)

Comment: @muru On macOS 11.6.5 (1.9.5p2) I get the same output for both commands (i.e. with and without `--preserve-groups`): `daemon everyone localaccounts com.apple.sharepoint.group.2 com.apple.sharepoint.group.1 com.apple.sharepoint.group.3 _lpoperator`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently it *does* work as I expected, it's just `groups` and CPython that retrieve groups in a way that is ignorant of sudo's work.

CPython (3.8.9) will return target user's groups regardless of `--preserve-groups`:

```
python3 -c "import os; print(os.getgroups())"
```

But the following Swift program will work as expected:

```swift
import Darwin

let count = Int(getgroups(0, nil))
var groups = [gid_t](repeating: 0, count: count)
getgroups(Int32(count), &groups)
print(groups.map({"\($0)"}).joined(separator: ", "))
```

Comment: This is decidedly weird. For me, `groups` works correctly, but Python works like you say it does. But *that* is [documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getgroups): "If built with a deployment target greater than 10.5, `getgroups()` returns the current group access list for the user associated with the effective user id of the process; the group access list may change over the lifetime of the process, it is not affected by calls to `setgroups()`, and its length is not limited to 16."

Comment: Oh, now I see. I had GNU utilities installed, and this was GNU coreutils' `groups`. `/usr/bin/groups` does work like you say it does.

Comment: Apple's `groups`, per docs, is equivalent to `id -Gn`. The `id` tool [uses `getgrouplist`](https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/shell_cmds/blob/3675cf36782e8339492447b881daf7f82f419859/id/id.c#L406) which ignores the groups that `sudo` sets via `setgroups` when the `--preserve-groups` option is given.